# Change the type string in ActiveRecord polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working with an existing dataset that I cannot really change for now. Fortunately I already have a `*_id` and `*_type` column in one of the tables. The problem is that the `_type` column is not the name of the class I want to associate with, it's an integer.

So for example I have:

Picture:

```
----------------
|id|x_type|x_id|
| 1|  1   | 1  |
```

Employee (x_type: 1):

```
---------
|id|name|
| 1|foo |
```

Business (x_type: 2):

```
---------
|id|name|
| 1|foo |
```

So the query is going to need to look for `x_type = 1` instead of `'Employee'` and `x_type = 2` instead of `Business`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a migration which creates a 'type column' and update the value with Employee where x_type is 1 and Business where x_type is 2. And make sure 'type' column is the one used for your polymorphic association.